# Post request with payload and headers returns error page

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying the get the content from a tvguide source https://sinematv.com.tr/Yayin-Akisi
With the below code, I receive an html page but it is just a runtime error message.
Most probably I am making a mistake when posting payload or headers.
What could be the problem?

```
url = 'https://sinematv.com.tr/Yayin-Akisi'
session = requests.Session()
request = session.get(url)
token = request.cookies['__RequestVerificationToken']
cookies = request.cookies

headers = {
    "authority": "sinematv.com.tr",
    "path": "/Asset/GetTvGuide/",
    "scheme": "https",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-TR;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "origin": "https://sinematv.com.tr",
    "referer": "https://sinematv.com.tr/Yayin-Akisi",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36",
}

payload = {"date": "16.10.2020", "__RequestVerificationToken":token}

response = requests.post(
    "https://sinematv.com.tr/Asset/GetTvGuide",
    data=payload,
    headers=headers,
    cookies=cookies,
)

print(response.content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong logic in getting token. It comes not from cookie, but from hidden element on page.

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://sinematv.com.tr/Yayin-Akisi'
session = requests.Session()
request = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, "html.parser")
token = soup.find("input", {"name": "__RequestVerificationToken"})["value"]


payload = {
    "date": "16.10.2020",
    "__RequestVerificationToken": token
}

response = session.post(
    "https://sinematv.com.tr/Asset/GetTvGuide",
    data=payload
)

print(response.content)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Also I made mistake when requesting the post, it has to be 'session' instead of 'requests' . Can you give a brief explanation why the logic is wrong?

Comment: There is no universal answer - it depends on how the website works. This site, as I looked in the js code, use token for request from `window.requestVerificationToken`. So in my variant I get it and use it.